# Table with dynamic number of columns

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table in which I display in the first line the current month
and I want to change the number of td in the second line whith ng-click function.
(if I click into a next button I get the next month and the number of td in the second tr become exactly the number of the day of this month(next month)

what I ve done :

```
$scope.nextMonth=function(month){
  var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
  var numMonth = months.indexOf(month);
  console.log(numMonth);
    if(numMois == 11){
      $scope.month= months[0];
    }
    else {
      $scope.month=months[numMonth+1];
    }
    $scope.nbrJrs = NbJourByMonth(numMonth,2016);
};
```

This is a screenshot of what I actually have :

[image: result]

**Edit**

and when I click next button I get this :
[image: next button png]

As you can see the month change but the number of td which refers to the number of day in the month doesn't change !! :(

In the view i have this :

```
<table>
<thead>
<th><a href="#" onclick="previousMonth()"><</th>  
<th class="col-md-4" colspan="{{NbJourByMonth(m,year)-2}}"><center>{{month}}</center></th>
<th><a href="#" onclick="nextMonth()">></th>   
</thead> 
<tbody>  
  <td id="{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="n in range(nbrJrs)">{{$index+1}}</td>  
</tbody>   
</table>
```

and this is the range function :

```
  $scope.range = function (count) {
        var ratings = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ratings.push(i)
        }
        return ratings;
    }
```

When I click into next flech I can change the name of the month and also I get the number of day in this month but the number of td doesn't change (I get 31 td I don't know how I can redraw the table.)
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Having worked with angular recently, the best way to get help in this community is to build what you have so far in Plunker so we all can tinker with it - https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 0):

@Akino

One option, you could make the colspan of the TH to be (number of days in a month) -2 and bind that dynamically using Angular.

```
<table>
  <th><!- Placeholder for Left Nav Button --></th>
  <th colspan="{{currentMonthDays-2}}">{{currentMonth}}</th>
  <th><!- Placeholder for Right Nav Button --></th>
  <tr>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="n in range(nbrJrs)">{{$index+1}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks so much @user1461064 for your replay but this is exactly what I ve done in the Th which contain the name of the month (I ve edited my question)

Comment: you ve not understood my question I wasn't so clear .. I have just add a picture to explain the problem can you please look at **Edit** part ?

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood the question. Instead of using function "range" in the ng-repeat, what you can do is on click, when you call previousMonth or nextMonth, set the dates in scope. 
`previousMonth = function() {
 ....
 $scope.currentMonthDays = [...];
 $scope.currentMonthName = '<name of the month>';
}

<table>
  <th><!- Placeholder for Left Nav Button --></th>
  <th colspan="{{currentMonthDays-2}}">{{currentMonthName}}</th>
  <th><!- Placeholder for Right Nav Button --></th>
  <tr>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="n in currentMonthDays">{{$index+1}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>`

Comment: Ok @user1461064 thank you sooo much for your unswer . I worked with angular directives .. I put my DOM code in a template and  when I click next or previous button  I reload the DOM .. even if  the application has become slow in loading data from the BD but this resolve my problem.